# Better way to get button setTitle?

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently I am doing this:

```
NSInteger senderTag = [sender tag];
```

But all I really want is the title/value of the button pressed not the tag id.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the text of your button's label by checking

```
NSString *txt = [sender titleLabel].text;
```

This is not as reliable as the tag, though, especially when your app changes the text on the label in response to user interactions or due to selection of a new locale.

Also note that to set the label you need to use a different method:

```
[sender setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```